# For field extensions $F\subsetneq K \subset F(x)$, $x$ is algebraic over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $x$ be an element not algebraic over $F$, and $K \subset F(x)$ a subfield that strictly contains $F$. Why is $x$ algebraic over $K$?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The thing is you need to understand what are the subfields in between $F$ and $F(x)$. If you have a subfield $K$ of $F(x)$ that contains $F$, then to allow $K$ to contain "more" elements than $F$ (i.e. to be distinct from $F$, but lie inside $F(x)$), $K$ must contain some element of $F(x)$, say $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \in K \cap F(x)$. But then this means $x$ is a root of $p(t) - q(t)\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \in K[t]$, hence $x$ is algebraic over $K$.

EDIT : @Aspirin : I assumed in my question that $F \subset K \subset F(x)$ because I thought it was clear from the context, but perhaps it is not. I think that in this case, **if you assume that $K$ is not a subfield of $F$**, you can replace $F$ by $F' = K \cap F$ so that $F' \subsetneq K \subsetneq F'(x)$. You clearly have $F' \subsetneq K$ by assumption on $K$ in this case (i.e. that **$K$ not contained in $F$**) and you get $K \subsetneq (K \cap F)(x) = K(x) \cap F(x)$ since $K \subseteq K(x)$ and $K \subsetneq F(x)$, hence is in the intersection, but if you had equality, it would mean $K = K(x) \cap F(x)$, and since $x \in K(x) \cap F(x)$, that would mean $x \in K$. In that case OP's question is trivial, so we can suppose we are not in that case. Also note that since $x$ is not algebraic over $F$ it is certainly not over $F'$. Therefore $F' \subsetneq K \subsetneq F'(x)$ and you can use the arguments above to show that $x$ is algebraic over $K$.

EDIT2 : I am leaving the preceding edit there because I still don't understand why it breaks down in the case $K \subseteq F$, which shouldn't work if we are still sane around here. I am more convinced that you need to assume $F \subsetneq K$ than the fact that my edit gives something good.

EDIT3 : After all those editings and reading the comments, I modified EDIT so that the case where $K \subseteq F$ is clearly not possible. The most general case where it would work is when $K \subseteq F(x)$ but $K$ is not a subfield of $F$. A slighty small detail dodged my eye and Dylan Moreland caught it, thanks to him. Note that this also proves that $x$ would be algebraic over $K$ if and only if $K$ is not a subfield of $F$ (assuming $K$ is described as in OP's question).

Hope that helps,

Comment: The OP can hopefully provide an argument for why this is a non-zero element of $K[t]$.

Comment: The question is technically easy but  difficult psychologically because one has to think of introducing a new indeterminate $t$.My experience is that beginners don't see that spontaneously . In the same vein the proof of  Lüroth's theorem (classifying such intermediate extensions) is not that easy to understand.  @Dylan's comment is an excellent test for self-checking the understanding  of the solution.

Comment: @Patrick: Can you explain case $F\not\subset K$? i.e. $\exists\alpha$ such that $\alpha\in F,\alpha\not\in K$

Comment: @Aspirin : I edited my question to answer your very pertinent question.

Comment: @Dylan : I don't think it is that hard, but I must admit I didn't think about it when I wrote my proof. I'll let OP answer that. =)

Comment: Maybe my editing of the title led to this confusion; I thought it made the question easier to pick out. I don't really understand the question if $K$ is allowed to be an arbitrary subfield of $F(x)$, though. What if $K$ is a proper subfield of $F$? Then nothing works out.

Comment: @Dylan : So I should understand that you don't agree with my edit?... Hmm. I see your point. Yes, this is indeed very troubling.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I'm still reading through your edit. It's more of a question to Asprin.

Comment: @Dylan : You raised a point that deserves giving it some thought. It would indeed be weird ; we expect no subfield of $F$ to have $K$'s property, but somehow my tricky argument says something.

Comment: If you want nitpicks, in the case of $K \subsetneq F$, the part that asserts $F' \subsetneq K$ certainly isn't true. Then the argument doesn't work, because you're counting on there being some element in $K \setminus F$, i.e. something that honestly contains an $x$.

Comment: @Dylan Moreland : Hm. So that would be the only problem?

Comment: I think I am done with all those edits, everything should be fine by now.